# When getChildren() returns an observable list with Circle as first element, how do I access the values in Circle?

Tags: java, javafx

I have to detect when two "balls" collide in a javaFX program. Each time a button is clicked, a new ball is added to the pane. I know that getChildren() returns an observable list that contains the node for each ball, and when I print the list with two circles it will print, for example, 
Circle[centerX=30.0, centerY=30.0, radius=20.0, fill=0x9ac26780], Circle[centerX=224.0, centerY=92.0, radius=20.0, fill=0x9ac26780]

My idea was to use nested loops to compare the (x,y) coordinates of each ball to every other ball. How do I access centerX and centerY from each Circle in order to compare them?
I tried getChildren().sublist(0,0); thinking that I would get the centerX value for the first element, but that does not work. I also tried getCenterX, because Ball extends Circle, but that also failed. Thanks for your time.

```
public class Exercise20_05 extends Application {
  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

MultipleBallPane ballPane = new MultipleBallPane();
ballPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: yellow");

Button btAdd = new Button("+");
Button btSubtract = new Button("-");
HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
hBox.getChildren().addAll(btAdd, btSubtract);
hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

// Add or remove a ball
btAdd.setOnAction(e -> ballPane.add());
btSubtract.setOnAction(e -> ballPane.subtract());

// Pause and resume animation
ballPane.setOnMousePressed(e -> ballPane.pause());
ballPane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> ballPane.play());

// Use a scroll bar to control animation speed
ScrollBar sbSpeed = new ScrollBar();
sbSpeed.setMax(20);
sbSpeed.setValue(10);
ballPane.rateProperty().bind(sbSpeed.valueProperty());

BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
pane.setCenter(ballPane);
pane.setTop(sbSpeed);
pane.setBottom(hBox);

// Create a scene and place the pane in the stage
Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 250, 150);
primaryStage.setTitle("MultipleBounceBall"); // Set the stage title
primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
}

private class MultipleBallPane extends Pane {
private Timeline animation;

public MultipleBallPane() {
  // Create an animation for moving the ball
  animation = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e -> moveBall()));
  animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE); //animation will play indefinitely
  animation.play(); // Start animation
}

public void add() {
  Color color = new Color(Math.random(), 
    Math.random(), Math.random(), 0.5);
  //creates a new Ball at (30, 30) with a radius of 20
  getChildren().add(new Ball(30, 30, 20, color)); 
  ballCollision();
}

public void subtract() {
  if (getChildren().size() > 0) {
    getChildren().remove(getChildren().size() - 1); 
  }
}

public void play() {
  animation.play();
}

public void pause() {
  animation.pause();
}

public void increaseSpeed() {
  animation.setRate(animation.getRate() + 0.1);
}

public void decreaseSpeed() {
  animation.setRate(
    animation.getRate() > 0 ? animation.getRate() - 0.1 : 0);
}

public DoubleProperty rateProperty() {
    return animation.rateProperty();
}

protected void moveBall() {
  for (Node node: this.getChildren()) {
    Ball ball = (Ball)node;
    // Check boundaries
    if (ball.getCenterX() < ball.getRadius() || 
        ball.getCenterX() > getWidth() - ball.getRadius()) {
      ball.dx *= -1; // Change ball move direction
    }
    if (ball.getCenterY() < ball.getRadius() || 
        ball.getCenterY() > getHeight() - ball.getRadius()) {
      ball.dy *= -1; // Change ball move direction
    }

    // Adjust ball position
    ball.setCenterX(ball.dx + ball.getCenterX());
    ball.setCenterY(ball.dy + ball.getCenterY());

    ballCollision();
  }
}

//check for ball collisions
protected void ballCollision() {
    /*System.out.println(getChildren().size());
    getChildren returns an observableList; this observableList is what
    keeps track of the balls (specifically, the nodes added to ballPane)
    added each time the + button is clicked
    */
    ObservableList ballList = getChildren();
    System.out.println(ballList.get(0));
    //if there are 2 or more balls, check for collision
        if (ballList.size() > 1) {
           //compare each (x,y) coordinate value to every other (x,y) value
            for (int i = 0; i < ballList.size(); i++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < ballList.size(); k++) {
//                    if (ballList.sublist(i,i) < 1) {
//                        
//                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Ball extends Circle {
 private double dx = 1, dy = 1;

Ball(double x, double y, double radius, Color color) {
  super(x, y, radius);
  setFill(color); // Set ball color
  }
 }

 /**
  * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
  * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   launch(args);
 }
}
```

Edit: Thanks to a couple of people, I was able to get the collision check to work. One ball will get removed, but I get the ConcurrentModificationException. Here is the updated method:

```
protected void ballCollision() {
    ObservableList ballList = getChildren();
    //if there are 2 or more balls, check for collision
        if (ballList.size() > 1) {
           //compare each (x,y) coordinate value to every other (x,y) value
            for (int i = 0; i < ballList.size(); i++) {
                for (int k = i + 1; k < ballList.size(); k++) {
                    Circle c1 = (Circle) ballList.get(i);
                    Circle c2 = (Circle) ballList.get(k);

                    if ((c1.getCenterX() <= c2.getCenterX() * 1.10 &&
                        (c1.getCenterX() >= c2.getCenterX()*.90)) &&
                       ((c1.getCenterY() <= c2.getCenterY() * 1.10) && 
                         c1.getCenterY() >= c2.getCenterY() * .90)){

                            ballList.remove(c2);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Final Edit: Thanks to David Wallace for taking his time to help me. The issue was that I was calling ballCollision inside the for-each loop of the moveBall method. Once I moved it outside the loop, it worked perfectly.

Comment: If you know all child nodes are `Circle`s, just do `ballList.get(i)`, cast to a `Circle` and call `getCenterX()`, etc.

Comment: @James_D thanks, that works. Now I have to remove a ball when a collision happens. When I try that, I get the ConcurrentModificationException. I think this is because I am trying to remove an element from the list while I am iterating over the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the `ObservableList` just like any other `List`.  You will probably want to cast the elements to the right class, as shown here.  Use the `hypot` method of the `Math` class to calculate the distance between the centres.

```
for (int first = 0; first < ballList.size(); first++) {
    Ball firstBall = (Ball) ballList.get(first);
    for (int second = first + 1; second < ballList.size(); second++) {
        Ball secondBall = (Ball) ballList.get(second);

        double distanceBetweenCentres = Math.hypot(
            firstBall.getCenterX() - secondBall.getCenterX(), 
            firstBall.getCenterY() - secondBall.getCenterY());

        if (distanceBetweenCentres <= firstBall.getRadius() + secondBall.getRadius()) {
            System.out.println("Collision between ball " + first + " and ball " + second);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That works quite well, thank you. The new issue is that when I try to remove one of the colliding balls, I get the ConcurrentModificationException. I think this is because I am trying to remove an element from the list while I am iterating over the list to check for collision.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, because if  you're using `get` to get things from the list, you're not iterating over it.  You didn't try to use a for-each loop did you?

Comment: One thing you might be able to do is to build a list of the indexes of the balls you want to remove, and remove them all when you've finished checking for collisions.

Comment: I am definitely using get, not a for-each. I posted the better method as an edit to my original post.

Comment: Updated again. It works, but my IDE is still showing the ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: To clarify, the exception only happens when a ball is removed.

Comment: Are you calling this in the middle of another for-each loop across the same list of balls, such as the one in the `moveBall` method?

Comment: Yes. I just moved it out out of the loop (but kept it inside the moveBall method) and the exception is gone. Thanks for your help!